# Maven Nexus can't find a dependency

Tags: maven, pom.xml, nexus, nexus3, apache-commons-lang3

I have Nexus OSS 3.29 installed on the local network and I am able to start and browse http://somehost:8081/. I uploaded `commons-lang-3.1.jar` to `maven-releases` and I can see it there. I have a Maven project in Eclipse where I defined a dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

In my `settings.xml`, I have repository defined:

```xml
<profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>java-net-public</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>java-net-public</id>
          <name>Java Net Public</name>
          <url>http://somehost:8081/maven-releases/</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
....
</profile>
.....
</profiles>
```

When I build my Project `Run As -> Maven Install with -e option`, I am getting an error:

> Could not find artifact commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:3.1 in java-net-public (http://somehost:8081/maven-releases/).

I tried to add repository definition to my `pom.xml` and it didn't work.

Comment: First I would suggest to put this configuration to consume from your repository manager only into the `settings.xml` and not in the `pom.xml`. Furthermore you can not find the given artifact because it does not exist with those coordinates and version...where I suppose the right coordinates are the following: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.12.0/jar

Comment: Thank you. I solved this issue by using correct repo URL :
http://somehost:8081/repository/<my group>

Answer (score 0):

Apparently when using Nexus as repository the URL should look like that :

http://somehost:8081/repository/

As soon as I added "repository" to the URL Maven dependencies got resolved.

Comment: What you have done is manually download "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3" from Central and uploaded it locally as "commons-lang:commons-lang", thereby breaking any relationship btwn the two. This is not good. Only you know this. What if there's a CWE (vulnerability) or ver. update, or even another jar declares it as dependency? Set up a proxy to Central in Nexus and use the real GAV.